# How to reload code when HTTP server is running?

Tags: julia

When starting an http server using HTTP.serve there is apparently no way to reload the code that is actually handling the HTTP request. 
In the example below I would like to have the modifications in my_httphandler taken into account without having to restart the server.
For the moment I need to stop the server from the REPL by pressing CTRL+C twice and then run the script again.

Is there a workaround ?

```
module MyModule

using HTTP
using Mux
using JSON
using Sockets


function my_httphandler(req::HTTP.Request)    
    return HTTP.Response(200, "Hello world")
end

const MY_ROUTER = HTTP.Router()
HTTP.@register(MY_ROUTER, "GET", "/*", my_httphandler)


HTTP.serve(MY_ROUTER, Sockets.localhost, 8081)

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether Mux caches handlers. As long as it does not, this should work:

```
module MyModule

using HTTP
using Mux
using JSON
using Sockets

function my_httphandler(req::HTTP.Request)    
    return HTTP.Response(200, "Hello world")
end

const functionref = Any[my_httphandler]

const MY_ROUTER = HTTP.Router()
HTTP.@register(MY_ROUTER, "GET", "/*", functionref[1])


HTTP.serve(MY_ROUTER, Sockets.localhost, 8081)

end


function newhandler(req::HTTP.Request)    
    return HTTP.Response(200, "Hello world 2")
end

MyModule.functionref[1] = newhandler
```

Comment: But how to you define this new handler once the http server has started? I guess my question is equivalent to "How to make julia take into account the changes in the code without having to restart the session and the http server?". Thanks Bill!

Comment: You might need to start the server with an @async before HTTP.serve(...) starts the server, if the problem is that you don't get the command prompt back .

Comment: Adding @async before HTTP.serve(...) gives me back the prompt, I can then rerun the lines of codes I want and the changes are indeed taken into account. Thanks!! One remark: Mux starts the http server in the background.

Answer (score 0):

[Revise.jl](https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl) lets you automatically update code in a live Julia session. You may be especially interested in `entr`; see Revise's documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

When using HTTP.jl: just add @async before HTTP.serve

```
module MyModule

using HTTP
using Sockets


function my_httphandler(req::HTTP.Request)    
    return HTTP.Response(200, "Hello world")
end

const MY_ROUTER = HTTP.Router()
HTTP.@register(MY_ROUTER, "GET", "/*", my_httphandler)


@async HTTP.serve(MY_ROUTER, Sockets.localhost, 8081)

end # module
```

When using Mux.jl: nothing to do, the server is started in the background

```
using Mux

function sayhellotome(name)
  return("hello " * name * "!!!")
end

@app test = (
  Mux.defaults,

  route("/sayhello/:user", req -> begin
    sayhellotome(req[:params][:user])

  end),

  Mux.notfound())

Mux.serve(test, 8082)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added a ticket [#587](https://github.com/JuliaWeb/HTTP.jl/issues/587) to HTTP.jl project for developer workflow support. I'm not sure this is your use case or not.

```
# hello.jl -- an example showing how Revise.jl works with HTTP.jl
# julia> using Revise; includet("hello.jl"); serve();

using HTTP
using Sockets

homepage(req::HTTP.Request) =
    HTTP.Response(200, "<html><body>Hello World!</body></html>")

const ROUTER = HTTP.Router()
HTTP.@register(ROUTER, "GET", "/", homepage)

serve() = HTTP.listen(request -> begin
                 Revise.revise()
                 Base.invokelatest(HTTP.handle, ROUTER, request)
          end, Sockets.localhost, 8080, verbose=true)
```

Alternatively, you could have a `test/serve.jl` file, that assumes `MyModule` with a top-level `HTTP.jl` router is called `ROUTER`. You'll need to remove the call to `serve` in your main module.

```
#!/usr/bin/env julia
using HTTP
using Sockets
using Revise

using MyModule: ROUTER

HTTP.listen(request -> begin
       Revise.revise()
       Base.invokelatest(HTTP.handle, ROUTER, request)
end, Sockets.localhost, 8080, verbose=true)
```

A more robust solution would catch errors; however, I had challenges getting this to work and reported my experience at [#541](https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl/issues/541) in `Revise.jl`.